# Reactivity on axios response data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set reactivity on my object retrieving by axios request

```html
<div v-for="plan in techs.plannings">
<span>{{plan.name}}</span>
 <div v-for="hour in plan.hours" >
    <button @onclick="changeHour(hour,4)"></button>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
data : (){
 return{
   techs : {}
  }
},
mounted : (){
 axios.get('initPlan').then((res) => {
        this.techs = res.data.techs
      })
},
methods: {
 changeHour(item,4) : {
     item.hour = 4
    }
}
```

The axios get request `initPlan` return an object like this          :

```
[
    {
        "plannings": [
                {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "June",
            "hours": {
                "2019-06-17": {
                    "hour": 2
                },
                "2019-06-18": {
                    "hour": 4
                }
                }
              }        
        ]
    }
]
```

When I run this code the `techs.plannings.hour` are not updated

Comment: Can you please share the json response you're receiving from your request to `initPlan`?

Comment: That code is full of syntax errors. I very much doubt it runs at all. Are you not getting floods of errors either from your IDE or in the browser console?

Comment: I edited my post thanks

Comment: As per your json - `"hours": [
                "2019-06-17": {
                    "hour": 2
                },
                "2019-06-18": {
                    "hour": 4
                }
                ]` Is this possible ? to have key : value inside an array ! Looks like invalid JSON

Comment: My bad sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing "in" in the **v-for** on your first line.

Change it to this instead:

```
<div v-for="plan in techs.plannings">
```

Your axios function should also be formatted like this, as an arrow function:

```
 axios.get('initPlan').then((res) => {
    this.techs = res.data.techs
 })
```